# Show blade code snippet inside a laravel blade view

Tags: laravel, markdown, laravel-blade

I am creating documentation for my blade based components in a laravel project and would like to display syntax highlighted blade code snippets as part of the documentation a la something like this:

[image: Desired result]

I have installed `graham-campbell/markdown` package and I try use it inside a .blade.php file as follows:

[image]

(Do not mind the escape character)

However, the output I get is as follows:

[image: Actual output]

Comment: What's the question? It works like it supposed to be?

Comment: First image is the output that I want to achieve, second is the code that I have right now, third is the actual output that I am getting.

Comment: Why not just replace the @ with &#64; This would circumvent the blade engine

Comment: It renders the `&#64;` instead of @

Comment: don't use the @markdown in that case, treat it as any other html

Comment: Wrapping it inside @verbatim might do the trick too

Comment: @verbatim outputs it simply as a plain string.

Comment: I am wondering what does laravel.com use in their docs to display the code examples?

Comment: a quick look at their docs shows me that they put the text behind the @ in a span `@<span>include</span>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the Blade in a `@verbatim` directive and use [Highlight JS](https://highlightjs.org) with a style you like

````html
<p>You can use the laravel code template like this</p>

@markdown
```php
@verbatim
@include('components.inputs.text', [
   'name' => 'input_name',
   'label' => 'testing',
])
@endverbatim
```
@endmarkdown
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/styles/a11y-dark.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
````

#### Result

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Saly3301 for coming to my rescue once again.